# DoctrineCommonCache garbage collection?

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, garbage-collection, doctrine

I have implemented a cache in my symfony2.8 application using [DoctrineCommonCache](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/caching.html) but I cannot find any information about how garbage collection is done on expired cache files. Is this something I must manually implement or is it done somehow? (The docs on this lib are severely lacking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you use the FilesystemCache class? If yes, there is no garbarage collection in it. This is also not needed, because why should the Cache file deleted? If the Cache has been expired, the next requests will create the file anyways. There is only a problem if you have dynamic cache keys, but this isn't recommend anyways.

Comment: yes, I am using FilesystemCache. Thanks for the reminder about dynamic keys. I hadn't considered it.